# ERROR : django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: users_customuser.email

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm learning Django but I keep getting this error when I type :

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: users_customuser.email

**I Have a Creating Superuser But I'm facing some Error till superuser run on Server. So, Give me A Solution of This Error.**

My `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from .managers import CustomUserManager

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    cpassword = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ("email",)
    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory, the email needs to be unique for your user table.